# UIScrollView animation problems

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiscrollview, objective-c-blocks, block

I'm using a horizontal UIScrollView that displays photos on the first half of the screen. (Imagine a CGRect (0,0,320,120). The first scrollView is embedded in a second scrollview, which takes all the screen. When I scroll down the page (thus the second scrollView), the first scrollview stop being animated. I programmed a NSTimer to change photo every 3 seconds in the first UIScrollView, but while I'm scrolling the second scrollView, it seems like the animations are being queued. When I release my finger of the screen, there are few photo transitions (i.e: 2 changes if I scrolled without stoping for 6 seconds). **In short:** how can I make use of blocks (or something else) to continue my animations while I'm scrolling the second scrollView?

My NSTimer (in viewDidLoad):

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changePage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iOS app has a run loop that continually checks for things like user input. If it is busy detecting touch events, things that are scheduled on that run loop will not get performed. (Similarly, if you block the main thread with e.g. a big server request, you won't get touch events during that time).

Here's how you can get the NSTimer on the right run loop:

First, use `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` to create a timer not scheduled on a run loop.
Second, use `- (void)addTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer forMode:(NSString *)mode` to schedule the timer on a run loop. For the mode argument (the run loop type), use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` to allow the timer to fire without having to wait on the main run loop.

Note that this same effect exists for e.g. `performSelectorAfterDelay` if done in the main run loop. It also applies to animation completion blocks. I'm not sure if there's an easy way around the animation completion block problem besides using CoreAnimation.

Comment: Hi MaxGabriel, thanks for your answer. I now used "timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changePage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];" to instanciate my timer, but now it doesn't work at all, even if I don't touch anything. I tried implementing addtimer, but I don't understand how it works. Perhaps you might have a real-life example of how this works? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the code probably looks like this: `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:<#NSTimer *timer#> forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

What this code does is first call the NSRunLoop class method `mainRunLoop`, which returns an instance of the NSRunLoop class--specifically the main run loop. Then, we use that run loop to add the timer but in the common run loop mode. Don't mind the <##> syntax--that's just how you do the little blue auto-complete bubbles in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!! I just don't understand how this works. Is this the same thing as a NSOperation? I read somewhere to make a queue "NSOperationQueue" and add operations "NSInvocationOperation" to it, but it didn't work.

Comment: The run loop is like a method that is called over and over that checks for input from things like the user or `NSConnection` objects. It also can fire timers. I don't have enough expertise to give a really good description of it, but I'm sure there are detailed ones out there. `NSOperationQueue` is totally different: it is a queue of tasks that need to be done. For example, if you had to do 1000 really time-consuming operations that would block the main thread, you might put them in an `NSOperationQueue`. NSOperationQueue is for multithreaded operation, just like Grand Central Dispatch.